# javascript & react: import относительно root, а не текущего элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs, path, include

сейчас в проекте когда надо вызвать `import` вспомогательного компонента зачастую приходится использовать вот такие конструкции:

```
import '../../tasks/task_one'
```

а можно ли двигаться через корень как-нибудь, чтоб получалось наподобие

```
import '$tasks/task_one'
```

под `$` я тут просто показал корень

мне кажется использование в данном случае абсолютного пути делает код более читабельным

есть ли такой функционал?

Comment: include? Это где вы include вызываете в реакте? Может импорт?

Comment: все, переработал :) конечно `import`, сейчас заменю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно в корень проекта добавить `jsconfig.json` файл со следующими настройками

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src"
  }
}
```

Если у вас проект в TypeScript-е, то можно в файле `tsconfig.json` написать те же самые свойства и все будет работать также.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        // .. тут другие настройки
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
}
```

---

Без  указания `baseUrl` результат будет таким если из `App.js` импортировать компонент.

```
import Button from "./components/Button";
```

А после настройки относительной пути результат будет таким

```
import Button from "components/Button";
```

Comment: секундочку, а во что превратятся тогда такие пути как выход из подпапок до src а затем вход в подпапки, т.е. если один Ts у меня лежит в `src/block1/subblock2/data.ts`, а второй, который находится в `src/block2/subblock5/data.ts` использует данные из первого файла, то приходится делать `../../block1/subblock2/data.ts`, что изменится в случае предложенного вами изменения? не надо делать `../../`? а как тогда находясь в block1 добраться до subblock2 - опять с корня стартовать?

Comment: @Zhihar Именно - не надо будет делать вот так `../../`. А чтобы добраться с `block1` до `subblock2` нужно написать вот так `./subblock2/data`, тут не надо стартовать из `src`. Либо если хотите добавить еще папки для старта, к примеру хотите стартовать из папки `components` или `core`, то советую смотреть в сторону `path aliases` ссылка тут  -> `https://habr.com/ru/post/557076/`

Comment: понял - а такой вопрос (если уж сталкивались) - это же мое желание - не блажь, не странная хотелка, а обычная ситуация когда много компонент и т.д.?

Comment: @Zhihar ну обычно во многих проектах это активируют, да. Если вопрос был в этом.